# Laravel, enable MCrypt for CLI

Tags: laravel, wamp, mcrypt

I know the question was asked a lot, but most answers were for linux/xOS systems and no thread about windows,

Lately I'm trying to learn laravel which need mcrypt extension enabled which was easy with wampmanager and it worked fine, but the CLI using php artisan doesn't work and only dd **Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.**

I only have one version of php and accessing the `php.ini`.

I only find

```
[mcrypt]
; For more information about mcrypt settings see http://php.net/mcrypt-module-open

; Directory where to load mcrypt algorithms
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
mcrypt.algorithms_dir=

; Directory where to load mcrypt modes
; Default: Compiled in into libmcrypt (usually /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt)
mcrypt.modes_dir=
```

I've tried configuring it by downloading `libmcrypt` and setting it in php\ext with no avail.

Comment: WAMP's PHP CLI config file is `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.x.y\php.ini` The Apache config actually lives in `c:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.x.y\bin\php.ini`. If you got it working via apache, copy the relevant setting from one to the other.

Comment: both files are alike, plus i jus activated mcrypt from wamp menu not from php.ini

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `php --ini` to find out which config files are loaded.

CLI could use another config-file than php.ini.

**EDIT:**

Make sure the file got these things correct:

`extension_dir` This should point to your extension-directory. There may be a line there which you could just uncomment. Otherwise it's probably "ext/" or something like that.

Also, make sure

`extension=php_mcrypt.dll` is uncommented.

You can use `php -info` to check what extensions are available.

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: didnt find "extension=php_mcrypt.dll" in the ini file but the ext directory made it for me :D